# Check today's date with column of dates return true / false in excel?

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I want to compare today's date with other sheet's column [which contains a list of date's] and in return, if today's date is not available in the list it should say no/false or show red in color.

For example:
I have an excel sheet with multiple sheets on it. On the summary sheet, I want to know the status of other sheets like whether the other sheets getting updated on time or not.

Comment: So, you're asking for `=A1=TODAY()` .. ?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Kind of. The apt word for the question is "check". I have made changes in the question. I want to check today's date in the list of dates [which is in another sheet from same excel sheet.] If today's date available in the list in return it should show green color or yes or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick your cell to format and apply a CF formula rule with red fill of:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!J:J,TODAY())=0
```

With `Sheet1!J:J` adjusted to suit.

Comment: Glad someone understood the question xD